# quotation mark (quotation sign) xelatex + polyglossia + csquotes

Tags: xetex, punctuation, polyglossia, csquotes

the problem I have is the "**?**" that shows instead of appropriate quotation marks (signs) when citing/quoting text in foregin language. I have searched manuals for the packages such as `polyglossia` or `csquotes`.

Unfortunately I haven't found a command that would allow me to declare quotation marks (signs) for the languages I am intending to use in my doc.

In the plain text I could of course use the `,,` or `''` to mimic the behavior of `enquote` but the bibliographic entries ale also affected by this unpleasant phenomena :(

```
% !TEX TS-program = arara
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

% arara: xelatex: { shell: true }
% arara: biber
% arara: xelatex: { shell: true }

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek,Scale=MatchUppercase]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont[Script=Cyrillic,Scale=MatchUppercase]{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{polish}
\setotherlanguages{english,latin,greek,russian,german}

\usepackage[strict=false,autostyle=true,english=american,german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\PassOptionsToPackage{%
        natbib=true,
        style=authoryear-comp,
        hyperref=true,
        backend=biber,
        maxbibnames=99,
        firstinits=true,
        uniquename=init,
        maxcitenames=1,
        citetracker=true,
        parentracker=true,
        backref=true,
        backrefstyle=two,
            }   {biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{Author2014,
    author      = {Joe, Smith},
    title       = {Publication title in polish language},
    journal     = {Journal of Journals},
    pages       = {1},
    year        = {2014},
    month       = {March}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

    \noindent{}{\enquote{\languagename{} \today}}\\
    \textenglish{\enquote{\languagename{} \today}}\\
    \textgerman{\enquote{\languagename{} \today}}\\
    \textlatin{\enquote{\languagename{} \today}}\\
    \textgreek[variant=ancient]{\enquote{\languagename{} \today}}\\
    \textrussian{\enquote{\languagename{} \today}}\\
    \textpolish{\enquote{\languagename{} \today}}\\
    \cite{Author2014}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `csquotes` does not know Polish and Latin as you can see in the log file.

> `Package csquotes Warning: No style for language 'polish'.`

So you will have to tell `csquotes` what kind of quotation marks you would like to see in a Polish text.

You might issue

```
\DeclareQuoteStyle{polish}% I looked it up on Wikipedia, no idea if it's right
  {\quotedblbase}
  {\textquotedblright}
  [0.05em]
  {\textquoteleft}
  {\textquoteright}

\DeclareQuoteStyle{latin}% this is just a copy of the German definition
  {\quotedblbase}
  {\textquotedblleft}
  [0.05em]
  {\quotesinglbase}
  {\fixligatures\textquoteleft}
```

in the preamble.

In general, you have to have a `\DeclareQuoteStyle` for each language `csquotes` does not know. The list of supported languages is in `csquotes.def` (you can find that file with `kpsewhich csquotes.def`). You can find other definitions for comparison there.

The syntax for the command is as follows (see [`csquotes` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/csquotes.pdf), esp. §8.1 *Defining Quote Styles*).

```
\DeclareQuoteStyle[variant]{styl}[outer init][inner init]%
  {opening outer mark}
  [middle outer mark]
  {closing outer mark}
  [kern]
  {opening inner mark}
  [middle inner mark]
  {closing inner mark}
```

If you know how to set up your language's quotation marks with `csquotes` and your language is not currently supported by that package, you may want to consider suggesting the maintainer to include it https://github.com/josephwright/csquotes/issues

[image]

Comment: works like charm :) thx