# Biblatex (biber) and bibliography in Ukrainian

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I have a file as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,ukrainian,english]{babel}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1 

\pdfcompresslevel=9 % сжимать PDF
\usepackage[bibencoding=auto,backend=biber,sorting=none,babel=other, style=ieee]{biblatex} % ieee or phys
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteAlias{english}{ukrainian}
\addbibresource{/home/vkudak/my_citations.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{SECTION}
\cite{klimik2010zaselenist},
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The problem begins in places where I have Ukrainian bibliography

```
@article{klimik2010zaselenist,
title={Заселеність геостаціонарної орбіти та результати її контролю},
author={Клімик, ВУ and Єпішев, ВП and Кудак, ВІ and Мотрунич, ІІ and Мацо, ГМ},
journal={Науковий вісник Ужгородського університету. Сер.: Фізика},
number={28},
pages={150--156},
year={2010},
hyphenation={ukrainian}
}
```

It looks like

> В. Клімик, В. Єпішев, В. Кудак, І. Мотрунич, and Г. Мацо, “Засе-
>   леність геостаціонарної орбіти та результати її контролю”, Науковий
>   вісник Ужгородського університету. Сер.: Фізика, no. 28, pp. 150–156,
>   2010.

but should be

> В. Клімик, В. Єпішев, В. Кудак, І. Мотрунич, **та** Г. Мацо, “Засе-
>   леність геостаціонарної орбіти та результати її контролю”, Науковий
>   вісник Ужгородського університету. Сер.: Фізика, **№**. 28, **С**.
>   150–156,2010.

No localization for Ukrainian: how to solve this?

Comment: See also [What is the most appropriate way to configure biblatex for use with an unsupported language?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200932/35864)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you write a `ukrainian.lbx` file yourself (long job: 400-500 items), which you'll have to put in the relevant place in the T.D.S. (and propose to the `biblatex/biber` staff), or, shorter, you write in your preamble lines such as:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ukrainian}{
and = {та},
number = {№},
pages = {С\adddot}
}%
```

and create in the same directory as your document an empty `ukrainian.lbx` file:

[image]

Comment: you mean put this preamble to TEX file or to BIB file ?

Comment: To the `.tex` file. One does not write any preamble to .bib files, as far as I know.

Comment: When I add preamble I get Error "Package biblatex Error: Language 'ukrainian' not found. " http://www.overleaf.com/3790207pqkmdm Maybe its only overleaf error ?

Comment: @Viktor: Please take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: This works, but the `year` field for books is now not displayed. What should be added?

Comment: That's quite strange… Could you post a question with a minimal example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @Bernard https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442587/165867