# Problem with year and jourvol in Ukrainian localization in biblatex/biber

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am using `biblatex-gost` package, `gost-numeric` style.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{samoylenko,
    title = {Диференціальні рівняння. Підручник},
    author = {А. М. Самойленко and М. О. Перестюк and І. О. Парасюк},
    location = {К.},
    publisher = {Либідь},
    year = {1994},
    pagetotal = {360},
}
@article{perestyuk,
    author = {Ю. М. Перестюк},
    title = {Розривні коливання в одній імпульсній системі},
    journal = {Нелінійні коливання},
    year = {2012},
    volume = {15},
    number = {4},
    pages = {494--503},
}
@book{hartman,
    langid = {english},
    title = {Ordinary Differential Equations},
    author = {P. Hartman},
    location = {Philadelphia},
    publisher = {Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics},
    year = {2002},
    pagetotal = {612},
}
\end{filecontents}       
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,maxbibnames=999,style=gost-numeric,language=auto,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ukrainian}{
and = {та},
number = {№},
page = {С\adddot},
pages = {С\adddot},
volume = {Т\addot},
%jourvol = {Т\addot},
}

\toggletrue{bbx:gostbibliography}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\cite{samoylenko} \cite{perestyuk} \cite{hartman}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Since there is no Ukrainian biblatex localization, based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280297/165867) answer, I added the `\DefineBibliographyStrings{ukrainian}` command.

But even after that I have two problems:

1. Year field is missing in bibliography (only in Ukrainian books, English are fine).
2. `jourvol` instead of the desired `Т.` (only in Ukrainian articles).

I tried adding `jourvol = {Т\addot},` but it produced the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence. \abx@sstr@jourvol
```

**UPDATED TWICE:** Here is a MWE displaying only the problem 1 (missing year field). When language is set to English everything works fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{samoylenko,
    title = {Диференціальні рівняння. Підручник},
    author = {А. М. Самойленко and М. О. Перестюк and І. О. Парасюк},
    location = {К.},
    publisher = {Либідь},
    year = {1994},
    pagetotal = {360},
}
\end{filecontents}       
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,maxbibnames=999,style=gost-numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\toggletrue{bbx:gostbibliography}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

This was studied in \cite{samoylenko}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

But I need `360 с.` instead of `360 pp.`. So I add Ukrainian language `\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel}`. Since my `pdflatex` is a little outdated, in does not contain a `ukrainian.lbx` file. So I create it manually with an empty content. Now I get

[image]

`pages` word can be translated using `\DefineBibliographyStrings{ukrainian}` command. But the year `1994` is gone.

Comment: Since version 3.8a `biblatex` has had a Ukrainian localisation: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commits/dev/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/ukrainian.lbx. I can run your example without problems and obtain the desired output. The years are present and everything seems to work fine. In the definition of `jourvol` you are missing a `d`, it must be `\adddot`, so you have to have `jourvol = {Т\adddot},`

Comment: You are right. Fixing `\adddot` helped, thank you. Is it possible to fix the year without updating the whole system?

Comment: Not sure. It depends on why the year is not displayed. It should be. Please do the following: Simplify your example even further to only deal with the year issue. (Do you need the translation to reproduce it? Do you need three references? ...) Then add `\listfiles` to the beginning of your `.tex` file. Delete all auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...). Run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX and upload the `.log`, `.blg` and `.bbl` file either to your question or to a text sharing website (like pastebing, GitHub Gist, GitLab snippets, **do not use a file sharing website**).

Comment: I updated the question with a MWE containing only 1 bibitem with a missing `year` field.

Comment: What output are you expecting? I get *Самойленко А. М.* Диференціальні рівняння. Підручник / А. М. Самойленко, М. О. Перестюк, І. О. Парасюк. — К. : Либідь, 1994. — 360 с. which seems to include the year 1994.

Comment: Like David Purton I obtain a reference with year from your second example. Remove both the `language=auto,autolang=other` and then try again. Does it work if you additionally switch from Ukrainian to English.

Comment: I updated the question again. Step by step displaying when the issue appears. Now without using `language=auto,autolang=other`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mention your system is outdated and does not ship with `ukrainian.lbx` (that file has been available in `biblatex` since version 3.8a).

If you simply create an empty `ukrainian.lbx` you don't get bibliography strings (`pages` is one example - it is bold indicating the definition is missing), but you also don't get so-called bibliography extras. Amongst other things the bibliography extras define the date format. If the file does not contain definitions for the date, in some situation the date might be swallowed silently and will not be printed.

Ideally you would update your outdated TeX system to TeX live 2018. In that case Ukrainian works out of the box and everything should be fine. If you can't do that or you don't want to do that because your are close to a deadline, you have to find a work-around.

You could try and get `ukrainian.lbx` from https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commits/dev/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/ukrainian.lbx and try if one of the older versions works for you. That is quite unlikely given that your system is so old now, the date handling changed a while ago, so the files are probably not compatible with your outdated system.

So your last resort is to write your own `ukrainin.lbx` for your outdated system. Take `english.lbx`, `german.lbx` or `russian.lbx` (you need the *exact* versions on your machine so we can be sure the file is compatible, usually you can find them with `kpsewhich russian.lbx`) as a basis and modify it as needed.

Comment: I took the `russian.lbx` file on my system (located it using `kpsewhich` command) and based on its content created a `ukrainian.lbx`. It finally worked! Earlier I tried downloading `ukrainian.lbx` from github's master branch and it didn't help. I didn't realize that the date format has changed in the new version. Thank you, *moewe*, you saved my couple of days!

Comment: FWIW I have submitted a pull request that will at least give sane date output and warnings in those situations in the future: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/775

Comment: OK, that might be helpful!

Comment: It is certainly helpful for those who read the warnings and act accordingly. For people who only look at the output it brings improvement (they get some output that might look right) and at the same time could be dangerous (it is only right on the first glance, people really should provide a proper definition for these macros in the `.lbx` file).