# Beamer Bibliography "and" and section name

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I am using Beamer to prepare a Turkish presentation.
However, I came a cross with the following two problems.

1. How can I make this write "Author1, Author2 ve Author3"?
2. How can I replace "References" with "Kaynaklar" in the top bar?

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[10pt,turkish,notheorems]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article {MR1708451,
    AUTHOR = {Zhang, B. G. and Tian, C. J. and Wong, P. J. Y.},
     TITLE = {Global attractivity of difference equations with variable delay},
   JOURNAL = {Dynam. Contin. Discrete Impuls. Systems},
    VOLUME = {6},
      YEAR = {1999},
    NUMBER = {3},
     PAGES = {307--317},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

\citeauthor{MR1708451}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}

\printbibliography

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is controlled by `.lbx` files, and there isn't one for the Turkish languge. So ideally, you should create a `turkish.lbx` file to add support for the Turkish language in `biblatex`. Of course, it may be a long job (`.lbx` files have > 500 lines).

Here is a workaround: patching the `english.lbx` file. You can add translations for keywords as you wish, along the pattern at work in the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,turkish,notheorems]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  references = {{Kaynaklar}},
  and = {ve}
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article {MR1708451,
    AUTHOR = {Zhang, B. G. and Tian, C. J. and Wong, P. J. Y.},
     TITLE = {Global attractivity of difference equations with variable delay},
   JOURNAL = {Dynam. Contin. Discrete Impuls. Systems},
    VOLUME = {6},
      YEAR = {1999},
    NUMBER = {3},
     PAGES = {307--317},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

\citeauthor{MR1708451}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}

\printbibliography

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See also [What is the most appropriate way to configure biblatex for use with an unsupported language?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200932/35864)