# Using biblatex with apa style and portuguesa language

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I'm trying to use apa style with biblatex but I get "Undefined control sequence." right after \printbibliography.

Here's the code:

```
\usepackage[main=portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex} %apagar o de baixo
\DeclareLanguageMapping{portuguese}{portuguese-apa}
```

If I remove the option "style=apa" it works well.

I get this warning "File 'portuguese-apa.lbx' not found!(biblatex) Ignoring mapping 'portuguese' -> 'portuguese-apa'."

I think the error origins because of not finding the file.

Found these files: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/latex/lbx.

But I don't know where to add the file.

Comment: I don't think that there is a portuguese-apa.lbx. Get e.g. spanish-apa.lbx (in the biblatex-apa-folder), make a copy as portuguese-apa.lbx, correct the words and then use this.

Comment: I tried to find the biblatex folder on windows but I can't.
I'm using Miktex.

Comment: You need the biblatex-apa folder. Check your log-file, it should tell you were the files are.

Comment: If you get a nice working `.lbx`, send it to me (APA style author) and I will include it with the style.

Comment: Found the folder, added a new file named portuguese-apa.lbx.
Still get the same error though.


Here's the file http://pastebin.com/KWYrDVZj

Comment: @PLK I think this one works. Has more things translated than mine but I can still not get texmaker to find it.
http://ftp.eq.uc.pt/software/TeX/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/latex/lbx/portuguese.lbx

Comment: Actually, that's the default biblatex `.lbx`. The APA `.lbx` would reference this, if it existed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to write up an answer? I know we had [something similar for normal `biblatex` already](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200932/35864), but [the question came up again](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312240/35864) and so an answer would be appreciated.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry to bother you again. Do you want to write up an answer, or do you think the question is sufficiently similar to the one I mentioned above to close as a duplicate?

Comment: @moewe: I added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't confuse `lbx`-files for biblatex and `lbx`-files for biblatex-apa. `biblatex-apa` needs some more translations and settings and so loads an additional `lbx`.

If for your language there is no `lbx` for **biblatex** you can follow the instructions in this question: [What is the most appropriate way to configure biblatex for use with an unsupported language?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200932/what-is-the-most-appropriate-way-to-configure-biblatex-for-use-with-an-unsupport)

To create the additional `lbx` for **biblatex-apa** open one of the existing `lbx` in `/tex/latex/biblatex-apa` and save it as `<yourlanguage>-apa.lbx` in your document folder or in some local texmf-tree. Then adapt the various definitions.

If you think your definitions are useful sent them to the biblatex-apa author so that he can add them to the package https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa.