# Referencing with Devanagari in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber

This is my MWE -

```
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@BOOK{म्हणी,
TITLE={मराठी भाषेतील असभ्य म्हणी व वाक्प्रचार},
AUTHOR={मराठे, अश्विनीकुमार दत्तात्रेय},
YEAR={2012},
PUBLISHER={ग्रंथाली}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{marathi}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumenrals]{Yashomudra} %Replace with any Devanagari font.

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \cite{म्हणी}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This MWE results in some error messages, e.g.:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \datecircaprint \mkbibdateapalongextra
                                                  {labelyear}{labelmonth}{la...
l.19 ^^I\cite{म्हणी}
```

See [the full `.log` file](https://pastebin.com/sEKB6abe) for further details. What could be the possible reason? How to solve this?

Comment: Where do you see an error message? The messages are all marked as `INFO`.

Comment: Probably not in the .blg file, but I have errors in the log. See line 736, 749 of the log file. I pasted blg file just in case it was needed.

Comment: that's a biblatex-apa problem. You are missing the language files.

Comment: How to solve it @UlrikeFischer?

Comment: As Ulrike says, you need an `.lbx` file for your language, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/310471/35864 and links. Since APA style is a bit tricky and the definitions needed by `biblatex-apa` need some work I would urge you to check out whether it would be possible to use one of the standard styles (`style=authoryear,` for example) instead of the highly specialised and American-centric APA style.

Comment: If you do `\DeclareLanguageMapping{marathi}{english-apa}` after biblatex, it compiles and you will see why you need to define a `marathi-apa.lbx` file (see the `biblatex-apa` folder for files for other languages). When the styles don't provide their own language-specific string definition files, biblatex picks up the babel/polyglossia language setting and so can plug in the relevant string constants that way, like the heading for 'bibliography' (e.g, see the contents of the `gloss-marathi.ldf` file in the `polyglossia` folder). Although mapping is available, and inheritance...

Comment: Also be sure to read the biblatex manual about transliteration support since biblatex supports correct sorting of Devanagari via transliteration.

Answer (score 1):

@Niranjan, replacing `\printbibliography` with `\bibliography{test}` and `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` helps. However, notice that the initials written in Devanagari are not properly recognised by the bibtex.

```
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @BOOK{म्हणी,
        TITLE={मराठी भाषेतील असभ्य म्हणी व वाक्प्रचार},
        AUTHOR={मराठे, अश्विनीकुमार दत्तात्रेय},
        YEAR={2012},
        PUBLISHER={ग्रंथाली}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{marathi} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{test.bib}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumenrals]{Yashomudra} %Replace with any Devanagari font.

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \cite{म्हणी}
    %\printbibliography
    \bibliography{test} 
    \bibliographystyle{apalike}
\end{document}
```

[image]