# Bibliography: biblatex-chicago falls back to English, using babel with bahasam option

Tags: babel, biblatex-chicago

I am using `\usepackage[bahasam]{babel}` in my preamble to enable support for Bahasa Malaysia, but biblatex-chicago falls back to English. It returns `Package biblatex Warning: Language 'bahasam' not supported. Using fallback language 'english' on input line 276.`

How can I make changes to bibliography strings like `edited by` into `disunting oleh`, `2nd Ed.` into `Edisi ke-2` and such?

As a side note, CTAN has the separate package `babel-malay` instead of `babel` with `bahasam` option. However, invoking `\usepackage{babel-malay}` in my preamble returns `!LaTeX Error: File 'babel-malay.sty' not found.` I am using Texlive 2017 on Windows.

Comment: Please tell how you are loading the `biblatex` package. Separately, have you tried `\usepackage[malay]{babel}` (instead of `\usepackage{babel-malay}`)?

Comment: `biblatex` has no support for `bahasam`. You will have to implement the support yourself, see [What is the most appropriate way to configure biblatex for use with an unsupported language?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200932/35864)

Comment: @Mico I tried `babel` package with all proxy options such as [malay] or [bahasam] and `biblatex-chicago` (not just the `biblatex`) package still falls back to English. Loading package `babel-malay` directly produces error `babel-malay.sty not found` as I described in my question above.

Comment: @moewe That's a really helpful link! Thank you.

Comment: @moewe I succeeded to implement support for `bahasam` in `biblatex-chicago` package with the method you had detailed in the given link. Would you put your comment as an answer with that link (if that is acceptable in tex.sx, and if my question is not considered a duplicate) or what should I do to take it off the unanswered list?

Comment: I think we can just mark it as a duplicate. BTW: If you think your translation is good enough you might want to ask the maintainers to include it in their package.