# Can I change words in bibliography to Turkish words?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Abbreviations in bibliography like "n" and "pp" or words like "Volume" and "and" come from English. I'm writing my thesis Turkish and except bibliography, there is not a problem but, like the picture below, the terms in red circle remain English and I want to change it.

For example "and" -> "ve" (Turkish)

[image: Picture of bibliography]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.5 cm, bottom=2.5 cm, left=3 cm, right=3 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\bibliography{dnm}
\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\begin{document}
Hello Word \cite{pdf_1}.  
\selectlanguage{turkish}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: `biblatex` does not currently support Turkish. If you are keen, you could work on a translation; https://github.com/plk/biblatex/wiki/Checklist-for-submitting-a-new-localisation-file-(.lbx)

Comment: A few months ago someone opened an issue at GitHub for Turkish support (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/867), but I don't think there has been any progress recently. Very related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200932/35864

Comment: Off-topic: Do you use pdflatex to compile your document? If so, the likely reason for why you're getting just the single letter "n" instead of "In" (with a dotted-capital-I) immediately before the name of the journal is that you are (probably) not loading the `fontenc` package with the option `T1`.

Comment: @DavidPurton I typed up a short CW-answer. If you would like to write a proper answer instead, I will happily delete it.

Answer (score 2):

*Update* Thanks to the efforts of two new contributors, the next version (v3.15) of `biblatex` will include a localisation for Turkish. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/867 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/975.

---

As David Purton [commented](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489300/can-i-change-words-in-bibliography-to-turkish-ones#comment1235364_489300), there is no Turkish localisation for `biblatex` yet, I'm afraid. `biblatex` relies on volunteers fluent in the language to provide localisation modules. If you want to help, you can get in touch at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/867, where a Turkish localisation was discussed a few months back.

You can have a look at [What is the most appropriate way to configure biblatex for use with an unsupported language?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200932/35864) and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/wiki/Checklist-for-submitting-a-new-localisation-file-(.lbx) for first steps and hints on creating an `.lbx` file.

If you want to know how earlier projects went, have a look at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/717 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/780 for Hungarian or https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/708 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/710 for Latvian.

Comment: The ideas written in " What is the most appropriate way to configure biblatex for use with an unsupported language?" solve my problem. Firstly it looks hard but actually easy way to change words in the bibliography.

Comment: @ömerkoçhan If you translated the full file, please consider contributing the file to the project. You can get in touch at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/867