# biblatex lithuanian

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm trying to compile a pdf using `\usepackage[lithuanian]{babel}`
but apparently `pdflatex` does not support lithuanian language yet. Is there any workaround how to change "**and**" and "**&**" in citations and bibliography?

Thanks a lot :)

Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, titlepage]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[L7x]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lithuanian]{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@book{huck1974reading,
  title={Reading statistics and research},
  author={Huck, Schuyler W and Cormier, William H and Bounds, William G},
  year={1974},
  publisher={Harper \& Row New York}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=apa,
url=false,
sorting=nyt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}


\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \cite{huck1974reading} 
\item \parencite{huck1974reading}
\item \textcite{huck1974reading}
\end{itemize}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200932/35864 describes the process of teaching `biblatex` a new language. If you can contribute a localisation for a missing language, please get in touch at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues. See also the recent https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/489300/35864. In your example you will also (additionally) need an appropriate localisation for `biblatex-apa` (see for example https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/75, https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/pull/38)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `biblatex` does not support lithuanian yet.

Look at https://github.com/LIKS/lithuanian.lbx - copying this file to your project directory should help.

I also commented out `style=apa`, with the following result:

[image]

Maybe this helps.