# Adding (partial) support for a non-SVO language in biblatex-apa

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, apa-style, japanese

I'm trying to add some partial support for Japanese in a document I'm making, which uses APA style (mostly English references, plus some in Japanese (the main text is in Japanese, I'm also using lualatexja and ployglossia plus csquotes if that matters), unfortunately I don't have any minimal working examples since I don't have any `lbx` files yet).

Although [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201280) covers a lot, my main question is that whether it's possible to add support for a SOV language which mostly tends to use postpositions rather than prepositions.
For example an entry in Japanese should look like `URL [from]` rather than `[from] URL`, so merely translating the "from" key in biblatex-apa's lbx file would result in a wrong sentence order. Same goes with a lot of biblatex's Action keys (for example, `bytranslator`), since there doesn't seem to be a `〈name〉` command to set the location of the main name before a suffix.

And what should one do in order to localize the APA style? Create 2 lbx files for `japanese-apa` and and `japanese` and put them in the main directory of the project?

**Edit**: This is how far I've come so far:
[image]

One issue is the date, it should be `２０１９年９月11日`, polyglossia actually does support Japanese dates, but for some reason it's not being used. The other issue is `から` which should be after the URL (It's a postposition equivalent to "from").
[Here](http://s6.picofile.com/file/8384263200/Sample.zip.html) is a zip file containing a working sample, not that lbx files are mostly copies from English. You will need lualatexja.

**Edit2:** The sample exceeds the limits, but [here](https://gist.github.com/zareami10/56974d918f9a467a0db262edf1a7be49) it is in a single text file on github. (also my account has been messed up so I can't even comment on/edit my own question, so...)

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide a minimal example, even if you didn't make any changes to the configuration yet. Just a small document with your packages and one or two references, a `.bib` file where these references can be found, a screenshot of 'when I compile this minimal document this is the result', and a description of what you want the result to be. Then it is much easier for potential answerers to find a solution.

Comment: Please post your LaTeX code in form of a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) so that it is also available in the future.

Comment: Any chance you can share your files not packed in a `.zip`? There are plain text sharing websites such as https://pastebin.com/, https://0bin.net/ or https://gist.github.com/ **if** it is not possible to reduce the example text files so far that you can just paste them directly in the question. I don't like downloading `.zip`s from sources I don't know and the URL of the file sharing website also doesn't sound too trustworthy to me.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: If Stack Exchange staff can for some reason not merge the two accounts so that you can not regain control over this post I suggest you re-ask the question with the account you do have control over and we then close this question as a duplicate of the new question. That may feel a bit iffy, but this is a very complex question so it is essential that you can reply to comments (and comment on answers) and edit your question directly without having to go through the review queue.

Comment: I haven't looked at your code, but from what I understand from the question this is going to be tricky: The `biblatex` localisation system still assumes quite a bit about the word order and sentence structure. If a different word order is required, one usually has to modify the field format or even the bibmacros. This is all doable, but the localisation system offers no shortcut there and most (if not all) styles may have difficulties when definitions are overridden. ...

Comment: ...  This can be seen (on a probably smaller scale than what would be necessary for Japanese) in the localisation file for Hungarian https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/dev/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/magyar.lbx and Latvian https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/dev/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/latvian.lbx. In short it is fair to say that `biblatex`'s localisation feature works rather well for Western European languages and becomes more and more problematic the further you go east from there.

Comment: Closed by request in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/523555/35864.