# Adding (partial) support for Japanese in biblatex-apa

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style, japanese

For such a support we face two kinds of main problems.

## Guidelines

As far as I'm aware APA doesn't actually provide any official instructions on L10N. So one could argue what would even mean to support Japanese within APA style.

## Technical Problems

Most of packages, even those which has some kind of support for L10N are centered around English or Indo-European languages with Latin scripts at best. So it makes it fairly hard to add support for languages such as Japanese (which for example tends to use postpositions rather then prepositions being an SOV language) without actually writing yet another package which will end up incompatible with a lot of other packages even if we consider the time and effort worth it.

### Possible Solutions

A good solution but a huge undertaking might be redesigning the L10N process of `biblatex`, providing more high-level flexibility to support different languages. But I see that highly unlikely, so in the meantime some non-hackish methods to change styles per bib entry (by `lnagid` for example) and the ability to add manual entries would save a lot of headache.

### A specific case

An obvious first step for a support would be copying some languages' `.lbx` and `-apa.lbx` files and translating some strings. Which would lead us to this ([here](https://gist.github.com/zareami10/56974d918f9a467a0db262edf1a7be49) is a sample `tex` file):
[image]

There are quite a few issues here, firstly, 'から' is a postposition unlike 'from' and should come after the URL (which might sound weird if considering the guideline). Secondly the date is completey wrong, it needs to be reordered and also needs suffixes for all 3 entries like '２０１９年９月11日'. Other problems might include not using Japanese parenthesis (and well almost all punctuation marks) which can lead to wrong spacing at points, dots being added after the name which isn't really usual in Japanese (I don't have much information about their typical stylings though).

I've managed to fix the first problem after looking into some questions and skimming thorough `biblatex-apa`'s sources by adding the following:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \iffieldequalstr{langid}{japanese}
    {\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
            \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{url}\OR\NOT\iffieldundef{doi}}
            {}
            {\iffieldundef{urlyear}
                {}
                {\printtext{\bibstring{retrieved}}%
                    \addspace
                    \printurldate
                    \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}}
                \iffieldundef{url}{}{\printfield{url}\bibstring{from}\adddot %
                \renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\relax}}}}} % if true

    {\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
            \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{url}\OR\NOT\iffieldundef{doi}}
            {}
            {\iffieldundef{urlyear}
                {}
                {\printtext{\bibstring{retrieved}}%
                    \addspace
                    \printurldate
                    \setunit{\urldatecomma}%
                    \bibstring{from}%
                    \setunit{\addspace}}%
                \iffieldundef{url}{}{\printfield{url}\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\relax}}}}} % if false
}
```

Which would give us (Do I need to redefine it on each entry for non-jp entries?):

[image]

But the date (the biggest issue) and the rest still remain, and all these are only for considering a single use case.

Comment: The biblatex maintainer announced a few days ago a first biblatex version with multiscript support, https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/416. But I certainly wouldn't use a so special style like `biblatex-apa` as a starting point for investigations - that is difficult to adapt even when no other scripts are involved.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer When using `luatexja` the different script gets handled well enough, I haven't had any issues regarding scripts so far, it's mostly about the styling (syntax differences, date differences etc). About APA, well yes APA is actually where a lot of such problems arise. But as I mentioned you can't use different styles for different languages that easily AFAIK, so if you use APA for English, you're stuck with it for Japanese too unless you redefine everything in a hackish manner I assume. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I wrote I wouldn't use the style as a *starting* point. I have no idea e.g. about japanese dates, but if I wanted to implement them, I would use one of the standard styles and try it there and when it works try to add this to apa (or ask the apa maintainer to  do it).

Comment: The first place to look for dates in APA is the `.lbx` files that come with the style - these define the data formats for various languages and it shouldn't been too hard to make for for Japanese since the dates are constructed from basic components of day/month/year etc. Take for example the data macros at the end of `english-apa.lbx` and try to change them to fit your required format.