# Biblatex language for non-english users

Tags: biblatex

How can I set the language of the bibliography so it's Romanian instead of English? I'm writing in Romanian and I need to set the bibliography language to it too. For now my bibliography is in English (I noticed it as the "and" between multiple authors is being printed as "and" instead of "și". Please help. Thanks in advance!

The bib file:

```
@book{math,
title = {Matematic\u a},
author = {Gigel, Grasu and Gina, Gega},
year = {2006},
publisher = {Editura 123},
edition = {3}
}
```

The .tex file

```
\documentclass[twoside, 10pt]{book}

\usepackage{type1cm}         
\usepackage[romanian]{babel} 
\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
% when including figure files
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliografie.bib}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english} %I wish for the language to be romanian
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: show a small complete example of your code. That makes it much easier to test our issue.

Comment: Is it ok now? :)

Comment: Remove the \input{presets}, we don't have this, but show if you are using babel or polyglossia there.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201280/134144 could be interesting.

Comment: Ulrike Fischer, I'm not using any packages there. I use babel.

Comment: Looks as if biblatex has not romanian support yet. Go to the folder \tex\latex\biblatex\lbx in your tex system, copy one of the lbx to your document folder and name it romanian.lbx. Then adapt in it the translations. Send the changed file to the biblatex maintainer, then they can include it.

Comment: As Ulrike says: `biblatex` has no Romanian localisation yet. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200932/35864. If you want to help contribute `romanian.lbx`, don't hesitate to drop by https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the package babelbib with BibTeX writing in Spanish with a bibliography containing entries in a lot of languages -- even some in Romanian, that is why I have the required packages installed here. Not biber, that one just gave me grief. Add the language in which the entry is written. I.e., I'd do:

```
@book{math,
  language =     {romanian},
  title =        {Matematic\u a},
  author =       {Gigel, Grasu and Gina, Gega},
  year =         {2006},
  publisher =    {Editura 123},
  edition =      {3}
}
```

Note the `language` tag.

```
\documentclass[twoside, 10pt, romanian]{book}

\usepackage{type1cm}         
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}

\bibliographystyle{babplain-fl} 

\begin{document}
  \cite{*}

  \bibliography{bibliograpie}
\end{document}
```

(Sorry, I'm totally ignorant of Romanian, so I can't tell if the output is right).