# Footnote display problem using romanian babel & chicago style

Tags: bibliographies, footnotes, chicago-style

#### What I use

1. TexMaker
2. Compilation is `LuaLaTex > Biblatex (with Biber) > LuaLaTex(2x) > PdfViewer`

#### Main purpose

The main purpose is `to have footnotes and bibliography displayed correctly` for a PhD thesis using Romanian language.

#### The Document

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
%-------------------------------------------
%Page setup
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}
\linespread{1.5}
%--------------------------------------------
% Fonts
\usepackage{fontspec}           % initialize fonts
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}   % main font
%--------------------------------------------
% Language
\usepackage[romanian]{babel} 
%--------------------------------------------
% BIBLIOGRAPHY & CITATION
\usepackage[backend=biber,isbn=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\providetoggle{blx@lang@captions@romanian} % show chapters in romanian
\DeclareLanguageMapping{romanian}{cms-romanian}
%--------------------------------------------
\usepackage{lipsum} % Lorem ipsum dummy text
%--------------------------------------------
\addbibresource{bibliografie.bib}
%--------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%--------------------------------------------
% Summary
\tableofcontents
\newpage
%--------------------------------------------

% START THESIS

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Main purpose of thesis}
Lorem ipsum\autocite[p. 34]{gadamer2001AdevarSiMetoda} dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\autocite{iser1972ReadingProcessPhenomenological}

\chapter{Acknowledgement}
Quis imperdiet massa\autocite[pp. 34-35]{pfister1988TheoryAnalysisDrama} tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula. Egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere\autocite{jahn2001NarrativeVoiceAgency} morbi leo. At in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi.

\chapter{Lipsum}
\lipsum [2]

% END THESIS

%-------------------
\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

#### Bib File

```
@book{pfister1988TheoryAnalysisDrama,
    address = {Cambridge},
    series = {European studies in {English} literature},
    title = {The theory and analysis of drama},
    isbn = {0-521-32060-7},
    language = {eng ger},
    publisher = {Cambridge Univ. Press},
    author = {Pfister, Manfred},
    year = {1988},
}
@article{jahn2001NarrativeVoiceAgency,
    title = {Narrative {Voice} and {Agency} in {Drama}: {Aspects} of a {Narratology} of {Drama}},
    volume = {32},
    issn = {00286087},
    doi = {10.1353/nlh.2001.0037},
    number = {3},
    journal = {New Literary History},
    author = {Jahn, Manfred},
    year = {2001},
    pages = {659--679},
}
@article{iser1972ReadingProcessPhenomenological,
    title = {The {Reading} {Process}: {A} {Phenomenological} {Approach}},
    volume = {3},
    issn = {00286087},
    number = {2},
    journal = {New Literary History},
    author = {Iser, Wolfgang},
    year = {1972},
    pages = {279--299},
}
@incollection{issacharoff1994JakobsonRoman,
    address = {Baltimore and London},
    title = {Jakobson, {Roman}},
    isbn = {0-8018-4560-2},
    booktitle = {The {Johns} {Hopkins} guide to literary theory and criticism},
    publisher = {The Johns Hopkins University Press},
    author = {Issacharoff, Michael},
    editor = {Groden, Michael and Kreiswirth, Martin},
    year = {1994},
    pages = {417--419},
}
@book{gadamer2001AdevarSiMetoda,
    address = {Teora},
    title = {Adev{\u a}r {\c s}i metod{\u a}},
    isbn = {973-601-684-6},
    language = {rum},
    publisher = {Bucure{\c s}ti},
    author = {Gadamer, Hans-Georg},
    year = {2001},
}
```

#### Warning log

[image: Warnings]

#### Pdf File errors

Footnotes

[image: Footnotes]

Bibliography

[image: Bibliography]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I removed the introduction from your post because it was not needed to understand the question (I upvoted as well because I think the question is good). One thing for clarification: you say your compilation includes "Bibtex with Biber", this terminology is a bit confusing because Bibtex and Biber are two different systems/tools. I assume you don't actually use the `bibtex` tool, and you just run Biber, is that correct? If not then this may be part of the problem, however I suspect the main problem is that you don't have Romanian localization for the bibliography installed.

Comment: Hi @Marijn! Thanks a lot for looking to my problem!

> I assume you don't actually use the bibtex tool, and you just run Biber, is that correct?

I use this setting in TexMaker, that is why I said I use Biber: https://redirect.is/vag6s1h

> I suspect the main problem is that you don't have Romanian localization for the bibliography installed

Can you please point me how to have localization? I use Zotero with Better BibTex and I tried different exports: Better BibLateX, Better BibTex, Biblatex, BibTex, but without success.

Comment: I've changed the mention of Bibtex in your question to Biblatex to avoid confusion. For the real issue: apparently Biblatex does not support Romanian yet, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539235/biblatex-language-for-non-english-users. You could provide a translation file yourself if you want, see https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/latex/lbx for examples in other languages.