# Biblatex warning on unsupported language in segment without citations

Tags: biblatex, babel, languages

I have a document in English using `biblatex` to which I need to add an abstract in another language that is supported by `babel`, but not by `biblatex`. I thought that this would not be an issue because the abstract does not contain any citations, but I am still getting a warning when I change the language. How can I resolve this?

PS: This happens also when I pass the `language=english` to `biblatex`, but I don't want to do that anyway because I do have some non-English bibliography entries whose language is supported by `biblatex`.

### A working example

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
% Not including 'csquotes' fires an unrelated warning.
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@misc{SampleEntry,
  author = {Author, Sample},
  title = {Sample Title}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{esperanto}
Saluton!
\selectlanguage{english}

Let us cite \cite{SampleEntry}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### The warnings

> Package biblatex Warning: Language 'esperanto' not supported.
>
> LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
>
> Package biblatex Warning: Please rerun LaTeX.

Comment: Mmh, also worth mentioning that adding `esperanto` to the mix in the document appears to lead to an infinite "Package biblatex Warning: Please rerun LaTeX." (it does for me).

Comment: I don't have a good answer here, but a few comments. First, this is really just a "warning" rather than an error so, unless you have bibliography entries in the rest of the document which require Esperanto, I don't think you need to worry about it. You can get rid of the infinite "Package biblatex Warning: Please rerun LaTeX." by adding `esperanto` to the list of `babel` languages in the preamble. Though, it seems wrong to me that `biblatex` does what it does when the language is not preloaded, which is legit, as far as `babel` is concerned. ...

Comment: ... Finally, if really want to get rid of the warning, perhaps take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201280/105447, and add a very simple .lbx file to appease `biblatex`. Though there might be better ways to do it.

Comment: The line number refers likely to internals of one imported package. So, this isn't the actual line number, where the error occurs.

Comment: A possible workaround: load both languages in the preamble with `\usepackage[esperanto,english]{babel}`, an then map Esperanto to English (meaning "just use English defaults since there's no support for it") with `\DeclareLanguageMapping{esperanto}{english}`.

Comment: @gusbrs Thanks, I think I will use the `DeclareLanguageMapping` workaround. Also, IMHO it's worth adding an answer containing that solution and the simple `.lbx` file trick so that I can accept it and the question doesn't look unresolved.

Comment: @aclow I think this would hopefully receive an opinion of someone more able than myself, particularly the infinite rerun issue. Let's see if it does. If it doesn't in, say, the next couple of days, feel free to ping me again, and I'll add an answer. (Though I'd say the `\DeclareLanguageMapping` workaround makes the .lbx suggestion sort of obsolete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex`'s language support is implemented in way that

- requires all used languages to be "known" beforehand (for `babel` this means, all languages you are going to use need to be announced as options to `babel`),
- tries to load `biblatex` localisations for all announced languages even if there are no citations/bibliographies in the portion of your document typeset in that language.

That means that your document compiles with fewer warnings as soon as you make it read

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[esperanto, english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{esperanto}
Saluton!
\selectlanguage{english}
Let us cite \cite{sigfridsson}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

You still get a warning that `esperanto` is unsupported in `biblatex`, because `biblatex` does not have an `esperanto.lbx`.

You may choose to ignore this warning or you may want to look into writing a suitable `esperanto.lbx` (cf. [What is the most appropriate way to configure biblatex for use with an unsupported language?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200932/35864)).

There are ways to "silence" this warning, but I would not recommend that, since silencing the warning could come back to bite you if you really want Esperanto citations/bibliography entries at some point.

[gusbrs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/105447/gusbrs) suggested a simple way to make `biblatex` shut up [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645993/biblatex-warning-on-unsupported-language-in-segment-without-citations#comment1609628_645993): Map Esperanto to English

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{esperanto}{english}
```

Or you can issue

```
\makeatletter
\protected\def\blx@langsetup#1{%
  \blx@lbxinput{#1}
    {\edef\blx@languagename{#1}}
    {}}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble to remove the code that generates the relevant warning.

---

While `babel` does not error if you don't pass `esperanto` as option and later use `\selectlanguage{esperanto}`, the result might be a bit off.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{esperanto}
\tableofcontents
\section{Foo}
Saluton!
\selectlanguage{english}
\tableofcontents
\section{Bar}
Lorem
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: ? contentsname ?]

and the warning

> ```
> Package babel Warning: \contentsname not set for 'esperanto'. Please,
> (babel)                define it after the language has been loaded
> (babel)                (typically in the preamble) with:
> (babel)                \setlocalecaption{esperanto}{contents}{..}
> (babel)                Reported on input line 6.
> ```

With

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[esperanto, english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{esperanto}
\tableofcontents
\section{Foo}
Saluton!
\selectlanguage{english}
\tableofcontents
\section{Bar}
Lorem
\end{document}
```

I get

[image: Enhavo]

I can't tell you if other more important features like hyphenation work in both settings, but this behaviour seems to suggest to me that at least at the moment, you should still announce all languages to `babel` as package/class options.

Comment: moewe, Not explicitly declaring "secondary" languages in the preamble, and letting them be loaded on the fly as needed in the document, is a documented feature of `babel`. See, for example, the "Mostly monolingual documents" section of the manual. So, I'd say it is at least "unfortunate" that `biblatex` reacts with an infinite rerun warning. The OP's case is particularly clear, the intended use of the secondary language is just for an Abstract, where `biblatex` has no role to play.

Comment: (Though I'm not sure the previous statement applies to `\selectlanguage` or only to `\foreignlanguage`. And, with `\foreignlanguage` the infinite rerun does not occur.)

Comment: Indeed, just using `\foreignlanguage` here (and not loading `esperanto`) is an alternative, and arguably simpler, solution. (Or the `otherlanguage*` environment).