Vietnamese warnings with babel and biblatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[vietnamese, british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{vietnamese}{Ngô Bảo Châu}

\end{document}

The above code compiles in PDFLaTeX, but I get two warnings:
Package babel Warning: No input encoding specified for Vietnamese on input line 146.

...

Package biblatex Warning: Language 'vietnamese' not supported.
(biblatex)                Using dummy definitions on input line 8.

How can I avoid these two warnings?
The first can be removed with \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}, but I feel like it isn't the correct way: this line should be nowadays obsolete, and there should be a more direct way to tell babel the correct encoding for vietnamese.

as far as I can see your workaround for inputenc is what it needs to be (or patch internal commands) you should report it to babel as a bug the file should be updated to check that utf-8 is enabled not just check if inputenc is loaded. for biblatex I think you need to make a lbx file following these steps https://github.com/plk/biblatex/wiki/Checklist-for-submitting-a-new-localisation-file-(.lbx)

This bug report has been copy-pased to the babel issues: https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/305

The biblatex package hasn't got any vietnamese translation. Indeed, the warning message is resolved by inserting the newly created file.
\begin{filecontents*}{vietnamese.lbx}
    \ProvidesFile{vietnamese.lbx}
    [\abx@lbxid]
\end{filecontents*}

This presents an opportune moment to translate the biblatex strings into Vietnamese.
I tried, with Google translate, some strings. Remind to translate the long string between the first couple of curly brackets and the abbreviated string between the second couple.
\begin{filecontents*}{vietnamese.lbx}
    \ProvidesFile{vietnamese.lbx}
    [\abx@lbxid]

    \DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
        bibliography = {{thư mục}{thư mục}},
        references = {{tài liệu tham khảo}{tài liệu tham khảo}},
        shorthands = {{sau đây được trích dẫn là}{được trích dẫn là}},
        editor = {{biên tập}{biên tập}},
        editors = {{biên tập}{biên tập}}}
    
    \endinput
\end{filecontents*}

End the file with the \endinput command.

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200932/35864
