# Question marks instead of quotation marks in references

Tags: biblatex, babel, csquotes

I am using BibLaTeX and Babel (catalan) and I get a weird error in the bibliography:the quotation marks are replaced by question marks. If a deactivate Babel everything works.

**Babel:**

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{caption}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{pifont}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[top=0.79in, bottom=0.79in, left=1.18in, right=0.79in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\begin{document}
[...]
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

**Without Babel:**

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{caption}
%\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{pifont}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[top=0.79in, bottom=0.79in, left=1.18in, right=0.79in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\begin{document}
[...]
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: The problem is "Package csquotes Warning: No style for language 'catalan'." [We need to make a new `catalan` style, see here how to do that.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166337/35864)   Having read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Summary_table_for_all_languages) on the subject though, If you agree with the usage there, go with `\DeclareQuoteAlias{greek}{catalan}`.

Comment: THANK YOU for this!  I actually had the "quotes" as question marks getting introduced around the titles of all the references when I switched to biblatex to handle OSCOLA citation style, which I mention here not so much for you but for future searchers. It is NOT easy to find what to do about question marks inserted around citation titles since most of the posts are about / for newbies :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem comes from `csquotes`.  Either set the quoting style on loading, via

```
 \usepackage[style=english]{csquotes}
```

or if this is only a problem in the bibliography itself, issue

```
\setquotestyle{english}
```

just before `\printbibliography`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=english]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{test,
  author =   {Author, A. N.},
  title =    {Title},
  journaltitle = {J. J.},
  year =     2000,
  volume =   15,
  number =   1,
  pages =    {4-8}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Note that it would be better style to load `babel` before both `csquotes` and `biblatex`.  Both these packages will use the options passed to `babel` when possible.  Unfortunately `csquotes` doesn't know `catalan`, yet.

Comment: THANK YOU for this!  I actually had the "quotes" as question marks getting introduced around the titles of all the references when I switched to biblatex to handle OSCOLA citation style, which I mention here not so much for you but for future searchers. It is NOT easy to find what to do about question marks inserted around citation titles since most of the posts are about / for newbies :-)