# \csquotes messing up Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, csquotes

I'm pretty new to LaTeX, but will try to be as clear as possible.

I'm writing a thesis in humanities, so quoting is quite significant for me - both in-text quotes and block quotes.

Therefore I'm using \csquotes package. But it manages to mess up my bibliography, as it shows question marks instead of quotation marks ("") for articles. Example:

- The result I get with csquotes loaded : Peebles, Gustav (2010). **?** The anthropology of credit and debt **?** In: Annual Review of Anthropology 39.1, p. 225.
- The result I get with csquotes not loaded (the result I need) : Peebles, Gustav (2010). **"** The anthropology of credit and debt **"** In: Annual Review of Anthropology 39.1, p. 225.

What I would like to know, is there an option to get the result I need with csquotes loaded as I need that functionality for my thesis.

My head of file (I need latvian as secondary language for some of the references):

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[UKenglish,latvian]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear-ibid,ibidtracker=context]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography}
```

Later in document I print bibliography (I load main chapters with input):

```
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\label{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\lhead{\emph{Bibliography}}
\printbibliography
\clearpage
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It is better to provide a complete, but minimal file when asking questions. Regarding `csquotes`, you should load it after loading `babel`. Just in case: you are writing in Latvian as your main language, right?

Comment: The problem here is that `csquotes` is polyglot but not panglot, it doesn't speak Latvian (in that it does not know how Latvian quotation marks are supposed to look like). You will have to teach it [quotation mark (quotation sign) xelatex + polyglossia + csquotes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166337/35864), or you can set the style manually [Question marks instead of quotation marks in references](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/228085/35864).

Comment: Also note that as jon pointed out above, you use Latvian as main language, because `babel` makes the language loaded last the main language of your document. `biblatex` does not support Latvian either, so if you want localisation there, you will have to provide it yourself as well, see [What is the most appropriate way to configure biblatex for use with an unsupported language?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200932/35864).

Comment: Thanks, basically silly mistake with babel. My primary language is English and changing that sorted everything out in a jiffy.

Comment: That's fine then. I'm not entirely sure what to do with this question now. From the current content of the question body it is clearly a duplicate of [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166337/35864) (or [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/228085/35864)), so I'm inclined to vote to close as a duplicate. From the comments though we've found out that the trouble was somewhere else entirely, and I have not been able to locate a definitive question for the order of babel languages ...

Comment: I'm voting to close as a duplicate of [quotation mark (quotation sign) xelatex + polyglossia + csquotes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166337/35864) because this is what the question body suggests, even though the OP's problems were solved differently (see comment above).