# Conflict betw. `csquotes` and `biblatex`

Tags: biber, csquotes

With `csquotes`, the title of the reference under `\printbibiolograhy`, in the code below, comes out spuriously bracketed by `?`, and conversely without it. The `*bib` file was processed with Biber.

What is the problem, how to fix it?

[image: With]
[image: Without]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=numeric, maxnames=999, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@phdthesis{jd-2005,
        author = {John Doe},
        title = {TITLE},
        year = {2005}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\listfiles

\title{TITLE}

\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\cite[pp. 25-27]{jd-2005}

\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe loading fontenc helps.

Comment: @Johannes_B it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228092/37907

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `csquotes` the MWE produces the following warning

```
Package csquotes Warning: No style for language 'nil'.
(csquotes)                Using fallback style on input line 22.
```

and also (though slightly less relevant here)

```
Package biblatex Warning: Language 'nil' not supported.
(biblatex)                Using fallback language 'english' on input line 22.
```

Essentially, the MWE loads `babel` and sets no language at all, which causes `babel` to pretend a language `nil` was loaded. Neither `biblatex` nor `csquotes` can deal properly with `nil`.

The solution is to always pass at least one language option when you load `babel` (or not to load `babel` at all). For most intents and purposes `english` is the standard language, so `english` (either globally in `\documentclass` or directly as a package option to `babel`) is the straightforward choice here, but you can of course select any language supported by `biblatex` and `csquotes`.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=numeric, maxnames=999, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite[25-27]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with nicely typeset quotation marks.]

---

I seem to remember that in older versions of `babel`, `babel` would error or at least throw a warning if no language was selected at all.

---

Note that there is no need to manually put the `pp.` in the postnote, `biblatex` can detect page ranges and adds the appropriate page prefix automatically.

There should also be no need for `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}` and `\phantomsection` to make the bibliography appear in the table of contents. Have a look at other values of the `heading` option (e.g. `subbibintoc`).

Answer (score 0):

I believe I was able to fix it by using the `English` option for `babel`, although I must concede that I'm not entirely sure why this worked. The code follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=numeric, maxnames=999, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@phdthesis{jd-2005,
        author = {John Doe},
        title = {TITLE},
        year = {2005}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\listfiles

\title{TITLE}

\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\cite[pp. 25-27]{jd-2005}

\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]