# csquotes and biblatex warning No style for language 'bahasai' and Language 'bahasai' not supported

Tags: babel, csquotes, texpad, macos

my tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[
  left=3cm,
  headheight=33pt,
  top=3cm,
  right=2cm,
  bottom=2cm,
  includehead,
  includefoot,
  bindingoffset=5mm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bahasai]{babel} % <---- main language last
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{15}\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \Large\bfseries \MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}\space \thechapter % <--- uppercase
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 0\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 30\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %%%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
  {\parindent \z@ \centering
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 30\p@
  }}
\makeatother


\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{LOGO_PLN.png}}
\lhead{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{LOGO_IP1.png}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=5cm]{LOGO_IP2.PNG}\\[0.25cm]
        \textbf{PT. INDONESIA POWER UJP ADIPALA}\\[1.75cm]
        \textbf{PROJECT ASSIGNMENT \\[4cm]}
        \textbf{RETROFIT PLC TWIDO KE PLC S7-200}\\[4cm]

        \textbf{Diajukan Oleh:}\\
        \textbf{Abdul Qoyyim}\\
        \textbf{SIC-257}\\[3.5cm]
        \textbf{PROGRAM ON THE JOB TRAINING}\\
        \textbf{DIKLAT PRAJABATAN ANGKATAN 23}\\
        \textbf{TAHUN 2017}
    \end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter*{LEMBAR PENGESAHAN}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[3]

\chapter*{ABSTRAK}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[5]

\chapter*{KATA PENGANTAR}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[6]


\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\listoffigures
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\listoftables
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\pagebreak

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{PENDAHULUAN}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Latar Belakang}
\lipsum[2-3]
\section{Perumusan Masalah}
\lipsum[3]
\section{Maksud dan Tujuan Project Assignment}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Ruang Lingkup}
\lipsum[5]
\section{Metodologi}
\lipsum[6]

\chapter{LANDASAN TEORI}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[7]
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{LOGO_IP3.png}
    \caption{a nice plot}
    \label{fig:mesh1}
\end{figure}

As you can see in the gambars \ref{fig:mesh1}, the 
function grows near 0. Alsos, in the page \cite{einstein} \pageref{fig:mesh1} 
is the same example. \lipsum[1-3]

\chapter{PEMBAHASAN PROJECT ASSIGNMENT}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[8]

\chapter{MANFAAT PROJECT ASSIGNMENT}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[9]
\section{Manfaat Finansial}
\lipsum[10]
\section{Manfaat Non Finansial}
\lipsum[11]
\chapter{KESIMPULAN DAN SARAN}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[12]

\section{Kesimpulan}
\lipsum[13-14]
\section{Saran}
\lipsum[14]
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title=Referensi]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The warnings are quite clear. Neither `csquotes` nor `biblatex` currently support Bahasa Indonesia. See [What is the most appropriate way to configure biblatex for use with an unsupported language?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200932/35864) and [quotation mark (quotation sign) xelatex + polyglossia + csquotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166337/35864) for what you have to do to make the two packages support Bahasa Indonesia.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/378585/35864