# Correcting quotation mark without autostyle=false{csquotes}

Tags: texpad, macos

Without `autostyle=false` in `csquotes` package the quotation show like this

[image]

with `autostyle=false` quotation show a correct typesetting but I need `csquotes` package for sentences quotation

[image]

here is the minimal code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[
  left=3cm,
  headheight=33pt,
  top=3cm,
  right=2cm,
  bottom=2cm,
  includehead,
  includefoot,
  bindingoffset=5mm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, bahasai]{babel} % <---- main language last
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[autostyle=false]{csquotes}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{15}\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \Large\bfseries \MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}\space \thechapter % <--- uppercase
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 0\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 30\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %%%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
  {\parindent \z@ \centering
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 30\p@
  }}
\makeatother


\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\begin{titlepage}
    \end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}



\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\listoffigures
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\listoftables
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\pagebreak

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{PENDAHULUAN}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{LANDASAN TEORI}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[7]

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{LOGO_IP2.JPG}
    \caption{a nice plot}
    \label{fig:mesh1}
\end{figure}

As you can see in the gambars \ref{fig:mesh1}, the 
function grows near 0. Alsos, in the page \cite{einstein} \pageref{fig:mesh1} 
is the same example. \lipsum[1-3]

\chapter{KESIMPULAN DAN SARAN}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[12]


\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title=Referensi]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess adding style=english is sufficient. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no quote style defined for your language and so csquotes uses a fallback (and warns you in the log!). You can add it like this (I copied the english quote style, but you can change it to your liking):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, bahasai]{babel} % <---- main language last
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\DeclareQuoteStyle{bahasai}%
  {\textquoteleft}
  {\textquoteright}
  [0.05em]
  {\textquotedblleft}
  {\textquotedblright}

\begin{document}
\enquote{blub} \enquote*{blub}
\end{document}
```